# expo typescript template generated with error

Tags: react-native, expo

I just started my first react native with expo and typescript project, I have upgraded my expo and nodejs to the latest version and then run this command

```
npx create-expo-app -t expo-template-blank-typescript
```

to generate a new project. however, I have no idea why there are some errors....

like **(Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'View'.)**

and **Operator '>' cannot be applied to types '{ styles: any; "": any; }' and 'Text'.**

can  someone help me?

**21/12/2022 updated** :

solution: remove Javascript and Typescript Nightly from VSC extensions**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

make sure the tsconfig.json file look like this:

```json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base", // this allow JSX to be used among other things
  "compilerOptions": {
    // you can set this to false for a more permissive setup
    "strict": true,
    // set this only for a more permissive ts typechecking
    "noImplicitAny": false,
  }
}
```

If that doesn't work:

- Try to build your project with `tsc` command to see if it fails
- Restart your IDE as sometimes is just an error with vscode

[`noImplicitAny` documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny)
[`strict` documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict)